# How to click (a React element) a button which is not visible until seen by Inspection(Ctrl +Shift +I)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a button which I have to click but the thing is that I can not click it until or unless I see it by the using Inspection.

Here is the Xpath for the same.

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button
```

and full xpath is

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[1]/span/span[1]/button
```

and outer HTML is

```
<button class="_5f5mN       jIbKX  _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">GET</button>
```

I have used some approaches.

```
br.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
br.find_element_by_xpath('//span [@type='button']
```

but it says there is no element present. How can I click it using selenium?

Comment: Could you share the website?

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `presence_of_element_located`() and following xpath

```
WebDriverWait(br,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='GET']"))).click()
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

If normal `webdriver` click does not work then induce `javascripts` executor.

```
btn=WebDriverWait(br,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='GET']")))
br.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
```